# How do I customize weapons?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain, how do I customize a weapon? I saw it in some pre-release gameplay for The Phantom Pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customizing weapons is not very hard, you just need to know where to look.

First things first: You need to have completed a mission where you

> Extract a Legendary Gunsmith

It's a Side Op, and is labeled as above. He'll become a part of your staff and you'll be able to customize weapons.

**You're now done with the above**, so how do you go about the actual "customization"?

- First you need to be in the ACC (Aerial Command Center), you get
  there by just calling your chopper for a transport.
- Next, you open your iDroid and go to the Mother Base tab and choose
  Customize.

**And there you go, you should now have several options for
   customization.**